# Email Template not being rendered properly by gmail and outlook

Tags: html, css, email, templates, html-email

I'm sending email using django, 
i have this django template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
    <div class="main_container" style="box-sizing: border-box;background-color: #f9f9f9;padding: 0 15px;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
        <div class="container" style="box-sizing: border-box;display: grid;grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(100px, auto) 100px;align-content: center;max-width: 700px;margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="header" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                <img src="cid:mindr_icon" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 90px;margin: 0 auto;display: block;">
            </div>
            <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box;background: #fff;border-radius: 15px;box-shadow: 0 0 10px #f3f3f3;color: #454c54;padding: 10px;">
                Test Email !
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">
                <div class="links_footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-template-rows: 1fr;padding: 30px 20px 10px 20px;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;text-align: left;">PRICING</a>
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">HELP</a>
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;text-align: right;">CONTACT</a>
                </div>
                <div class="social_footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 10px;display: grid;grid-template-columns: 18px 18px 18px;grid-auto-rows: 18px;grid-gap: 18px;width: 90px;justify-content:center;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:fb_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:tw_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:in_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="made_with_love" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 10px;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 800;color: #575858;word-spacing: 2px;width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;">Made with <span style="color: #e25555;box-sizing: border-box;">&#9829;</span> By ____ Team</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the HTML isn't rendered correctly by most email clients, so i wanted to know what i could change to fix this issue.

i have tested Gmail, Outlook and MailSpring so far, and the only email client showing the email correctly is MailSpring

Thank You !

**Mailspring:**
[image]

**Gmail:**
[image]

**Outlook:**
[image]

Comment: Remove display: grid and try other display properties.

Comment: i have tried flex, but  it didn't work either

Comment: Try inline-block

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best way to make the templates display similarly on all email clients is to use tables and inline CSS. However, not all CSS properties are supported on all email clients so you might want to check which have ok support and which not.

Here is the list of all properties and their support: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Answer (score 1):

`Display: grid` and `Display: flex` are not supported in the mail template. Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
    <div class="main_container" style="box-sizing: border-box;background-color: #f9f9f9;padding: 0 15px;width: 100%;height: 100%;margin: 0;">
        <div class="container" style="box-sizing: border-box;display: grid;grid-template-rows: 100px minmax(100px, auto) 100px;align-content: center;max-width: 700px;margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="header" style="box-sizing: border-box;">
                <img src="cid:mindr_icon" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 90px;margin: 0 auto;display: block;">
            </div>
            <div class="content" style="box-sizing: border-box;background: #fff;border-radius: 15px;box-shadow: 0 0 10px #f3f3f3;color: #454c54;padding: 10px;">
                Test Email !
            </div>
            <div class="footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 20px;text-align: center;">
                <div class="links_footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;display: grid;grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;grid-template-rows: 1fr;padding: 30px 20px 10px 20px;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;text-align: left;">PRICING</a>
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">HELP</a>
                    <a href="#" style="box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;text-align: right;">CONTACT</a>
                </div>
                <div class="social_footer" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 10px;display: inline-block;">
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="display: inline-block; width: 18px; margin: 0 6px; box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:fb_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="display: inline-block; width: 18px; margin: 0 6px; box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:tw_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="social" style="display: inline-block; width: 18px; margin: 0 6px; box-sizing: border-box;text-decoration: none;color: #454c54;font-weight: 800;">
                        <img src="cid:in_ico" style="box-sizing: border-box;width: 18px;">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="made_with_love" style="box-sizing: border-box;padding-top: 10px;font-size: 13px;font-weight: 800;color: #575858;word-spacing: 2px;width: 80%;margin: 0 auto;">Made with <span style="color: #e25555;box-sizing: border-box;">&#9829;</span> By ____ Team</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```